# Mongoid after/before_remove callback is not triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, mongoid

I have the following relationship between Classroom and Student models :

```
Classroom has_many :students
Student belongs_to :classroom
```

In my Classroom model I have these relation callbacks :

```
has_many :students,
    after_add: :update_student_count,
    before_remove: :update_student_count


  def update_student_count(student)
    self.student__count = students.count
    self.save
  end
```

In my Student controller I have :

```
def destroy
   student = Student.find params[:id]
   student.destroy!
   redirect_to action: :index
 end
```

However `student.destroy!` never triggers the `before_remove` callback in my Classroom model. 
I have tried writing the action destroy in the following way to be executing the destroy action on the classroom instance but it seems destroy cant be used in this way with mongoid...

```
  def destroy
    student = Student.find params[:id]
    classroom= student.classroom
    student.destroy!
    classroom.students.destroy(student)
    redirect_to action: :index
  end
```

Why is my before_remove callback never executed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `before_destroy` instead.
Here's the [Mongoid](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html) docs for callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Just to flush out teddybear's solution, I think you could do something like this:

```
class Student
  belongs_to :classroom

  after_destroy :update_student_count
  after_create :update_student_count

  def update_student_count
    classroom.update_student_count
  end
end

class Classroom
  has_many :students

  def update_student_count
    self.student__count = students.count
    save
  end
end
```